# No sound devices (HDMI) with XUbuntu 22 after clean minimal install

Tags: sound, xubuntu, hdmi

I have a mini-PC that was working reliably as a media server...until it wasn't. One day it just refused to boot.

I did a clean install of XUbuntu 22 using the latest installer, selecting the "Minimal installation" option. Apt update and upgrade, and installed a few basic packages like SSH server and VLC.

So far so good. I configure the mount point to my NAS, and try to play a movie. There is no sound. Wait, I know this - I go to the sound mixer to select the HDMI output device...only there isn't one. The only output audio device listed is "Dummy output".

I have two HDMI ports so I unplug the TV from the first and plug into the second. No difference.

I don't remember having this problem when I first set the system up. I am sure it just worked.

I have read every guide I can find on the internet. They all seem to be very out of date or not relevant.

Please can someone help me!

```
$ lspci -v
00:0e.0 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor High Definition Audio (rev 06)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Sound
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor High Definition Audio
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 132
    Memory at a1310000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at a1000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [80] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci-intel-apl
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl, snd_soc_avs, snd_sof_pci_intel_apl
```

Comment: I suspect that "*XUbuntu 22 using the latest installer*" means Xubuntu 22.04.4. But a few weeks ago, "latest" meant 22.04.3. Best to use accurate release names and numbers whenever possible. Avoids a lot of confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I am not entirely sure what fixed the problem. Firstly I found this article: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=285225

This person's system is slightly different to mine - the responses he gets to some debugging commands is a bit different, but I ran the commands anyway, and then rebooted (after doing the stuff described in the second section below):

```
echo "options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
echo "blacklist snd_soc_skl" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

I now have the HDMI device listed, and the "Dummy Output" device has gone, which is what this was meant to achieve.

---

I also noticed that I seemed to have both PulseAudio and Pipewire running at the same time. So I followed this guide to disable Pipewire: https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=18449

I ran these commands after the above commands but before rebooting:

```
systemctl --user --no-legend --no-pager | grep pipewire*
systemctl --user stop pipewire.service pipewire-media-session.service pipewire.socket
systemctl --user disable pipewire.service pipewire-media-session.service pipewire.socket
```

Note that the services listed in the second two commands are all the services listed by the first command.

After rebooting sound was working fine, so I did the final command from the second article:

```
systemctl --user mask pipewire.service pipewire-media-session.service pipewire.socket
```